# Centering Div box in Div Box

Tags: css, html, alignment, center

I have add the footer to [EasyCareBath.com](http://www.easycarebath.com), and I can get the div to work properly except for ".footer_box", it will not center.  I have added "left: 15%" and when you blow the window up, it's no longer aligned.  Am I missing something or did I do too much to the css?

```
.footer_spacer {
    height: 50px;   
}
.footer_wrapper {
    height: 375px;
    background-color: #e6dccb;
}
.footer {
    border-top: 10px solid #789E65;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    margin-top: 0px;
    /*min-width: 1007px;*/
    height: 235px;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-image: url(../images_footer/footer_bg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: center top;
    position: relative;
}
.footer_box {
    height: 236px;
    width: 1007px;
    /*position: relative;*/
}
.footer_copyright {
    width: 100%;
    /* [disabled]height: 100px; */
    /*float: left;*/
    padding-top: 15px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    word-spacing: normal;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    color: #354245;
}
#footer_col_01 {
    position:absolute;
    left:11px;
    top:3px;
    width:164px;
    /*height:230px;*/
    z-index:1;
}
#footer_col_02 {
    position:absolute;
    left:186px;
    top:3px;
    width:164px;
    /*height:230px;*/
    z-index:1;
}
#footer_col_03 {
    position:absolute;
    left:361px;
    top:3px;
    width:164px;
    /*height:230px;*/
    z-index:1;
}
#footer_col_04 {
    position:absolute;
    left:535px;
    top:3px;
    width:183px;
    /*height:230px;*/
    z-index:1;
}
#footer_col_05 {
    position:absolute;
    left:728px;
    top:3px;
    width:265px;
    /*height:230px;*/
    z-index:1;
    font-size: 14px;
}
footer {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 11px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
footer a {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
footer a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
footer h6 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #00A1CC;
    line-height: 46px;
    /*margin-bottom: -2px;*/
}
footer li {
    line-height: 18px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 12px;
}
.footer_img_center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: In the future, you can usually get faster assistance if you put your CSS in markup in a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: I'm not sure why this got downvoted - seems to be a legitimate question.  Maybe because you included the actual link that will be soon out-dated? Either way, seems a valid question, so I'll up-vote to counter the mass-downs. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your css as following:

```
.footer_box {
    height: 236px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 1007px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Alter your `.footer_box` rule to this:

```
.footer_box {
    height: 236px;
    width: 1007px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    }
```

The `margin: 0 auto;` centers the footer_box.

The `position: relative;` makes it so your absolutely positioned columns are positioned based on the `footer_box` instead of the body.

Side note / an analogy I've always liked:
Think of the 'auto' as attaching a rubber band to that side of the item connected to the edge of the page... in this case, 'auto' is on the right AND the left, so - if there's a rubber band pulling from both left AND right, it will always center, regardless of screen size.

Comment: You are awesome! It worked perfectly!  I have seen similar answers but they did not include the "position: relative" with the "Margin"  thanks again!

Comment: This answer is true - just to add to it, you technically don't need "px" after 0 - because 0 is 0. Don't need to use any units & looks cleaner.

Comment: @Andy - yah - 'px' is not needed - just a habit I've never broken - I still like how it looks with the 'px' but something I should probably break. :)  (I'll remove it from the answer)  Thanks.

Comment: @dgPehrson - likely the reason `position:relative;` never came up is that normally people don't absolutely position columns - it's generally not good practice and should be done with `float:left;` instead.

Comment: @Andy - I personally think that 0px looks cleaner and prevents errors when you're tweaking the style. It also saves you from adding / removing 'px' everytime you change the dimensions.

Comment: @Dave - thanks for the advice, I will play around with that.  I found that absolute positioning works better for things I want done exactly.  I'm still young in CSS so I have much practice to do.

Comment: @LéonRodenburg I don't think it looks cleaner, takes more time to type extra characters for each time you type '0' and saves on a few bytes for each time.  Plus 0px = 0em = 0% = 0 - so why not just type 0. 0 is 0, no need for dimensions. And saving time is true-but for when you're typing 0 to start - "every time you change the dimensions to save time" - you would only need to type px once, if you still are changing dimensions I'm assuming you'd never go back to 0... Kind of like you never do `margin:1px 1px 1px 1px;` - because if you want change one it "saves time" - I think that's ridiculous.

Comment: @Andy Okay, but it's your opinion, which you now correctly mentioned. In your first comment you were stating it as a fact. And typing margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px is a whole other story, so it's kind of strange to bring it up because you can't compare the two.

Comment: Enough pls :)  To each their own, and either one is completely fine.

Comment: @LéonRodenburg Correct. It's a fact you don't need it. You're the one who had to weigh in your opinion. Just helping because it's not needed, saves time & saves small bytes of space.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track:

```
.footer_box {
    height: 236px;
    width: 1007px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

The auto margin on left and right will make sure the footer is always centered, no matter what the screen size is.